# git branches and running programs

Tags: linux, git, version-control

I am running a program in a git repository on a linux server. This program periodically calls another program in that repository. If I do a git checkout 'otherbranch' in the middle of execution will it suddenly start calling the version of that program in the other branch?

I'm new to git and don't understand the intricacies yet. How does git affect things like program execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do git otherbranch, the program in the other branch is checked out. And most of the time, if the call has not happened yet, the calling program will call the new program. It might depend on the nature of the calling program though.

And IMO this has nothing to do with Git. Git doesn't affect program execution. The program does. All git controls is what content is there in the filesystem.

Comment: So once I start execution of a program in a repository I'm not allowed to checkout another branch until execution is complete? Thats kind of annoying. Is there any way to run a program in a particular git branch instead of whatever branch the HEAD is pointing to at the time? Or I suppose since everyone isn't complaining about this, what is the standard way to deal with this?

Comment: @JTS - Run the program out of another clone of your repo.